# Join result of three queries into one query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add the result of three queries into one query:

```
select file_name,count(distinct uniq_key) FILE_LOAD_REC_COUNT from STG_STRR_CTDI_CMTX2_TEMP1 group by file_name;
select file_name,count(distinct uniq_key)  ERR_REC_COUNT_M from STG_STRR_CTDI_ERR_DESC1 where err_desc in ('DUPLICATE RECORD','MISSING MANDATORY DEVICE DETAILS') group by file_name;
select file_name,count(distinct uniq_key)  ERR_REC_COUNT_O from STG_STRR_CTDI_ERR_DESC1 where err_desc not in ('DUPLICATE RECORD','MISSING MANDATORY DEVICE DETAILS') group by file_name;
```

I want the result in the below format:

```
FILE_NAME|FILE_LOAD_REC_COUNT|ERR_REC_COUNT_M|ERR_REC_COUNT_O
ABC.json|10|10|20|29
```

How can i go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Union all two tables

SELECT file_name,
           COUNT (DISTINCT uniq_key) FILE_LOAD_REC_COUNT,
                 0 ERR_REC_COUNT_M,
                 0 ERR_REC_COUNT_O
   FROM STG_STRR_CTDI_CMTX2_TEMP1
   GROUP BY file_name
   UNION ALL

SELECT file_name,
                    0 FILE_LOAD_REC_COUNT,
                    COUNT (DISTINCT CASE
                                        WHEN err_desc IN ('DUPLICATE RECORD',
                                                          'MISSING MANDATORY DEVICE DETAILS') THEN uniq_key
                                    END)ERR_REC_COUNT_M,
                          COUNT (DISTINCT CASE
                                              WHEN err_desc NOT IN ('DUPLICATE RECORD',
                                                                    'MISSING MANDATORY DEVICE DETAILS') THEN uniq_key
                                          END) ERR_REC_COUNT_O
   FROM STG_STRR_CTDI_ERR_DESC1
   GROUP BY file_name

2. query after Union

SELECT file_name,
       SUM (FILE_LOAD_REC_COUNT) FILE_LOAD_REC_COUNT,
           SUM (ERR_REC_COUNT_M) ERR_REC_COUNT_M,
               SUM (ERR_REC_COUNT_O) ERR_REC_COUNT_O
FROM
  (

SELECT file_name,
           COUNT (DISTINCT uniq_key) FILE_LOAD_REC_COUNT,
                 0 ERR_REC_COUNT_M,
                 0 ERR_REC_COUNT_O
   FROM STG_STRR_CTDI_CMTX2_TEMP1
   GROUP BY file_name
   UNION ALL

SELECT file_name,
                    0 FILE_LOAD_REC_COUNT,
                    COUNT (DISTINCT CASE
                                        WHEN err_desc IN ('DUPLICATE RECORD',
                                                          'MISSING MANDATORY DEVICE DETAILS') THEN uniq_key
                                    END)ERR_REC_COUNT_M,
                          COUNT (DISTINCT CASE
                                              WHEN err_desc NOT IN ('DUPLICATE RECORD',
                                                                    'MISSING MANDATORY DEVICE DETAILS') THEN uniq_key
                                          END) ERR_REC_COUNT_O
   FROM STG_STRR_CTDI_ERR_DESC1
   GROUP BY file_name
   )
GROUP BY file_name;

Comment: Thanks a lot @dzungnv38 , this is what exactly i was looking for, it works great. Really appreciate your help. Cheers